# Can i make Excel save after a specific day of the week?

Tags: if-statement, automation, save

My idea is that i want my workbook to save automatically when the workbook is opend after every sunday.  so if i open the workbook at monday morning it will save the workbook at a folder with a new weeknr in the name every week.

my first thought was doing it with IF statements but im not sure thats the way.

Comment: You can run a macro [when your sheet opens](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44), but this obviously requires permissions to run VBA code. You can achieve pretty much the same by opening your file through a batch file or similar - where you can put your automation before opening excel. Involves some date and file copy gymnastics, but is simple and free.

Comment: @MyICQ can you show me how that macro could look like?

Comment: You can combine [onOpen](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/auto-open-macro/)   with  [SaveAs](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-save-as/). The examples given here should be enough to get a start. Is this enough to get you started ? You should at least know how to edit VBA macros and execute them.

Comment: Im not that to vba but im learning :D
But i will try to make something work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to go the VBA route, you can start with something like this:

First save your initial woorkbook as `filename.xlsm` (excel with macros enabled). Otherwise nothing will work.

Then enter VBA editor using `ALT-F11`. Click "This project folder" and make an _open event macro.
Order of action as here:

[image: VBA editor window showing order of adding OPEN macro]

You can use this code as a skeleton:

```vb
Const myBaseName As String = "opopen"
Const myBasePath As String = "c:\temp\"

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   ' get a new date
   d = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhnnss")
   newname = myBasePath & myBaseName & "_" & d & ".xlsm"
   
   MsgBox "NEW NAME IS ==> " & newname, vbOKOnly, "Information"
   
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs newname
   
End Sub
```

Obviously you can / should add some logic to make this change file only once per week. Use some date formatting to get week number, check file existence etc.
In my example, I make a new filename based on time, accurate to seconds - to prove the concept.

The weeknumber can be acquired using

```vb
   Dim wk As Integer
   wk = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now())
   wks = wk  ' as string
   If wk < 10 Then
      wks = "0" & wk
   End If

   ' use wks for weeknumbers, formatted to two digits.
```

*First time* you open this file you will have to confirm activation of macros. If you do saveAs from VBA, you should know that

- you *immediately* work with the new filename. You do not "save a copy as"
- the new file will have VBA macros enabled as well
- if you rename the file from Windows, you will have to reconfirm macros enabled.

Is this enough to get you started ?